# Protecting nchan's websocket channels using X-Accel

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy, nchan

I'm trying to hide/protect our WebSocket channels using this [approach](https://nchan.io/#x-accel-redirect) from the documentation.
Our setup is next:

1. Nginx server with nchan lives on `push.dev.com`
2. Upstream that performs the authentication lives on `app.dev.com`

The locations part of a `nginx.conf` for a server with nchan looks like this:

```
location /push/ws/subscribe {
    proxy_pass https://app.dev.com/api/ws_verify;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
}

location ~ /push/internal/ws/(.*) {
    internal;
    nchan_subscriber                            websocket;
    nchan_channel_id                            $1;
    nchan_websocket_ping_interval               10s;
}
```

The handler on `app.dev.com` listens on `/api/ws_verify` and, for simplcity, always returns an empty 200 response with the headers like

```
X-Accel-Redirect: /push/internal/ws/channel1123,
X-Accel-Buffering: no
```

And naturally, this "accelerated redirect" is being handled by nginx that lives on `app.dev.com` (and this nginx knows nothing about an internal location at `/push/internal/ws/(.*)`).

Is there a way to initiate an internal redirect from another server with nginx? Thanks.